# How to extract SubjectAlternativeNames form PKCS10 request

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#10

I would like to extract the subject alternative name (SAN) from a PKCS10 request in JAVA.

Fist, I get the PKCS10CertificationRequest using bouncycastle as follow:

```
PKCS10CertificationRequest certificationRequest = getPKCS10CertificationRequest(csr);
```

But then, I don't know if there a way to extract the SAN value from certificationRequest.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    byte[] der = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0])); // for example
    // assuming all BouncyCastle classes imported as needed and 
    // given a CSR in der, to get the SAN extension as an object
    // (minimal error handling, you may want to improve)
    Attribute[] attrs = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(der).getAttributes(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest);
    if( attrs.length != 1 ) throw new Exception("bad");
    ASN1Encodable[] valus = attrs[0].getAttributeValues();
    if( valus.length != 1 ) throw new Exception("bad");
    Extension extn = Extensions.getInstance(valus[0]).getExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName);
    if( extn == null ) throw new Exception("missing");
    // to get the _value_ of the extension, now extn.getExtnValus().getOctets()
    // to _use_ the _value_ of the extension, parse as GeneralNames:
    GeneralNames sanv = GeneralNames.getInstance(extn.getExtnValue().getOctets());
    for( GeneralName item : sanv.getNames() ){ // example of possible usage
        System.out.println (item.toString()); // you probably want something else
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this complet answer :) ,, I had this error when I try to calculate attrs : The method getAttributes(DERObjectIdentifier) is undefined for the type PKCS10CertificationRequestJava(67108964)

Comment: zero: make sure you use the PKCS10CertificationRequest in `org.bouncycastle.pkcs` (in bcpkix) not the (deprecated!) one in `org.bouncycastle.jce` (in bcprov). I didn't notice there were two.